# Clojurescript `:optimizations :advanced` breaks access to dataset

Tags: clojurescript

Following code:

```
(set! (.. e -target -dataset -some-field) "some-value")
```

is compiled into:

```
return a.target.dataset.Qh=Yf(b)
```

`some_field` is compressed into `Qh`. And I need it to be exactly `some_field`.

I understand this is due to compression optimization. But is there a way to hint, or to bypass this behavior?

PS: `simple` optimization gives the desired output

```
return a.target.dataset.some_field=cljs.core.name.call(null,b)}
```

Comment: Core team's recommendation seems to be [to use `goog.object/set`](https://github.com/cljs/api/issues/128) for setting object fields; also you can add the dataset's structure to the externs file.

However, both approaches seem overly verbose / complicated; I will be happy to know if there is a simpler recommended solution.

Comment: In addition to defining an extern, you may need to use `-some_field` instead of `-some-field`.

Comment: @AlephAleph cool, I'll try with `goog`

Comment: @exupero kebab-case will be compiled into snake-case I beleive

Answer (score 3):

You may also be interested in the `cljs-oops` library:   https://github.com/binaryage/cljs-oops

Then you can say:

```
(oset! el "innerHTML" "Hi!")
```

More examples below, and also [on the CLJS Cheatsheet](http://cljs.info/cheatsheet/):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `some-field` (or is it `some_field` or `someField`?) gets simplified to `Qh`. This  is because the compiler does not know that the `dataset` object has a `some-field` property.

- One solution is to write [extern files](https://clojurescript.org/guides/externs) so that the Google Closure Compiler will know that the given field must not be renamed.
- An other solution is to use [aset function](https://cljs.github.io/api/cljs.core/aset) or call [goog.object.set function](https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.object.html). This way you reference the field of the object with a string value and the string values do not get simplified.

Second example:

```
cljs.user=> (def a (clj->js {"a" 1}))
#'cljs.user/a

cljs.user=> a
#js {:a 1}

cljs.user=> (aset a "b" 2)
2

cljs.user=> a
#js {:a 1, :b 2}
```

Comment: Note that the first argument to `aset` should be an array, and the second should be a numeric index. See [Checked Array Access](https://clojurescript.org/news/2017-07-14-checked-array-access) for more info.

Comment: thank you for the link, i did not know that. looks like now i have a lot of cljs code to review. PS: i love your blog!